# Kotlin smart-cast assumes too much?

Tags: kotlin, generics, casting

I was reading here:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#type-erasure-and-generic-type-checks

When I came upon this:

```
fun handleStrings(list: List<String>) {
    if (list is ArrayList) {
        // `list` is smart-cast to `ArrayList<String>`
    }
}
```

And I had a nagging feeling that the smart-cast might be assuming too much about the generic parameter that it's casting too. AKA, how does it know that list is `ArrayList<String>` as opposed to `ArrayList<some subtype of String>`

I then wrote the following, which is a silly example but doesn't it violate the invariance of class B's parameter?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val test:B<String> = B()
    val dest:A<Any> = test
    if (dest is B) {
        val flaw:B<Any> = dest
    }
}

open class A<out T>
class B<T>:A<T>() {
    fun consumer(inbound: T) = Any() //the return is irrelevant
}
```

Basically what I tried to do above is leverage the out descriptor on class A to assign a `String` parameterized object to an `Any` parameterized variable, and then used smart-cast to make it a class B object again.

**Edit:**
Tenfour04 has commented with a great continuation of my example:

```
fun main() {
    val test:B<String> = B()
    val dest:A<Any> = test
    if (dest is B) {
        val flaw: B<Any> = dest
        flaw.consume(5)
        val x: String = test.produce()
    }
}

open class A<out T>
class B<T>:A<T>() {
    val list = mutableListOf<T>()
    fun consume(inbound: T) {
        list.add(inbound) 
    }
    fun produce():T = list.first()
}
```

Comment: Isn’t it smartcasted to `ArrayList<out String>` rather than what you said? How are you determining what it was smart casted to?

Comment: Extending your example a bit, I think you’re onto something. https://pl.kotl.in/YEJRKjk1M

Comment: The last example is very interesting, I would have expected a smart cast to `B<out Any>` instead, which would prevent `flaw.consume(5)`. Even funnier: when I remove the type declaration `B<Any>` from `flaw`'s declaration, IntelliJ shows the type `A<Any>` and yet lets calls to `consume` and `produce` compile, despite their absence in class `A`.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug. If you explicitly state the `out` projection in your function signature as `fun handleStrings(list: List<out String>) ` then the compiler will do the right thing. Please report at https://kotl.in/issue :)

Comment: I believe it's already reported as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7972